# Why doesn't a warning appear when -0 is written in the code?

Tags: c, linux, testing

I was testing a code and I accidentally put -0 in a line of code and noticed that no warning appears. The line of code is:`while(--argc>-0)`. I compiled the program with make. Why doesn't a warning appear when -0 is written in the code?

Comment: What is wrong with the expression?

Comment: `-0` is still `0` (zero). So, it's the same as: `while(--argc>0)`. So, given that, _why_ would you think you _should_ get a warning? `while(--argc>N)` where N is _any_ integer constant (e.g. `-40, 367, -1000000`) is _valid_ syntax

Comment: What warning did you expect?

Answer (score 2):

You may not realize that integer constants in C cannot be negative. `-0` is parsed as two tokens, the unary minus operator `-` and the integer constant 0.  Applying unary minus to zero is well-defined, it just produces zero again; an angry mob of mathematicians would assault the C committee if it wasn't defined that way.  So, the C compiler doesn't think this is a mistake.

However, if you wanted a warning because you meant to write `while(--argc>=0)`, go ahead and file a feature request on your C compiler. Typo detection has been getting popular lately, they might well like the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You do not get a warning because this is well defined C code and experience has not shown code like this is indicates programmer error often enough to be worth warning about.